# magento - how to add custom discount

Tags: php, magento, discount

I need to add custom discount to order. I've created an observer as displayed below:

```
$shippingDiscountValue = 20;
$currentAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$currentDiscount = (-1) * $currentAddress->getDiscountAmount();
$newDiscount = $currentDiscount + $shippingDiscountValue;
$quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $shippingDiscountValue)
    ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $shippingDiscountValue)
    ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $shippingDiscountValue)
    ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $shippingDiscountValue)
    ->save();  

$currentAddress->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $currentAddress->getSubtotalWithDiscount() - $shippingDiscountValue);
$currentAddress->setGrandTotal((float) $currentAddress->getGrandTotal() - $shippingDiscountValue);
$currentAddress->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $currentAddress->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() - $shippingDiscountValue);
$currentAddress->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $currentAddress->getBaseGrandTotal() - $shippingDiscountValue);        

$currentAddress->setBaseDiscountAmount($newDiscount * (-1));
$currentAddress->setDiscountAmount($newDiscount * (-1));

$currentAddress->save();
$quote->save();
```

I call this observer after any change in my cart (add, remove, update quantity). In cart details everything is OK - discount is calculated correctly, but in checkout (and in order) there is base amount of discount, without `$shippingDiscountValue`.

Comment: Why not just discount from the order using a Shopping Cart Promotional rule?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do this. Discount is set for every product separately (product A has 5 $ discount, product B has 7 $ discount), sum of them should be added for discount in cart (I've got rule: 10 % discount for all, so if I order products A and B, so my discount is: 10 % * (price A + price B) + 5 (product A discount) + 7  (product B discount).

Comment: You can apply specific discounts to specific products by using the SKU attribute in the Promotional rules.  You can also set the Special Price on the individual products to show it as "On Sale" with the discounted price.  You don't need to modify any code to achieve what you're requesting.

Comment: There is issue when you are using the paypal payflow payment method.
PayPal gateway rejected the request. Field format error: 10413-The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.